# iterating over a changeable iterator in every iteration

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to implement the code below, and I'm getting an error of 
"index is out of range". I think I am getting the error because the for loop saved the value of the length of the array, while I changed it inside the loop itself.

I can't figure out how to solve it using a for loop.
I did solve it using a recursive way, but it was computationally expensive and I am dealing with billions of words. BTW, the Comp function only returns a pool if the 2 words having the same sentence, so I believe it doesn't effect.

I am using Python-3, pycharm.

```
def reg(array,n):
    f=open(r"C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\love.txt","w")
    length= len(array)

    if length==1:
        return array
    k=0
    for item in range (length-1):
        k+=1
        for j in range(k,length):
            if Comp(array[item][0],array[j][0])>=n:
                f.write(str("\n"))
                f.write(str(array[item][1]))
                f.write(str("\n"))
                f.write(str(array[j+k ][1]))
                array[k+j]=array.pop()
                length-=1
                break
    f.close()
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the array, just keep track of your effective last index and break out when you hit it. Something like (untested)

```
k = 0
last_index = len(array) - 1
for item in range(length - 1):
    if item > last_index:
        break
    k += 1
    # ....
        array[k+j] = array[last_index]
        last_index -= 1
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem is I need to iterate over this func. multiple times, and if that is so, the last index will always be the same as the length of the array, what I need to do is that the elements who passed the Comp function to be removed so, If I used this function again with different n value the previous elements who passed the Comp function will not be compared again. I hope you can understand my broken English

Comment: Can you just remove from `last_index` to the end after the for loop completes?

Comment: I tried that already before I comment, but it didn't work, the problem is it works as a code but the result is not what I am expecting I am trying to post the result but as this segment is a part of 400+ line of code it will a real miss if I posted the result or the whole code, but in either way I would like to thank you for answering

Comment: I am currently trying to modify the original function so that it takes last index as another arg. so I can keep subtracting from it in each iteration.